# Are there two different self adjoint operators the bounds of spectrum of which coinside

Tags: functional-analysis

Are there two different self adjoint operators $A$ and $B$ , $(Ax,x)\ge (Bx,x)$, the bounds of spectrum(end points) of which coincide.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Example: $A=$ multiplication by $\arctan(t)$ in $L^2(R)$, $B=$ multiplication by $\arctan(t-1)$ in $L^2(R)$. For both, the spectrum is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: And why A>B? or it is wrong?

Comment: Because $\arctan t >\arctan (t-1)$ for all $t$, so $\int |x(t)|^2\arctan t\,dt>\int|x(t)|^2\arctan (t-1)\,dt$ unless $x\in L^2$ is the zero element

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you also want $\langle Ax,x\rangle >\langle Bx,x\rangle$ for some $x$, because otherwise $B=A$ is always an example.

You can take $H=\mathbb C^3$, and 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}, \ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\langle Ax,x\rangle\geq\langle Bx,x\rangle$ for all $x$, but for $x=(0,1,0)$ you have $\langle Ax,x\rangle=1$, $\langle Bx,x\rangle=0$.